# Регулярные выражения (как изменить)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть такая регулярка:

```
([a-z\d\-_\.\/]{2,255})?(p|tv|reel)/([\w\d_\-]+)/*
```

Она должна принимать ссылки вида:
https://instagram.com/p/IotHsfNf
https://instagram.com/ro_day/p/IotHsfNf

Пока она принимает только первую ссылку. Нужно сделать так, чтобы и вторая принималась. Подскажите пожалуйста как изменить регулярку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я конечно не специалист но это работает:

```
([a-z\d\-_\.\/]{2,255})?(p|tv|reel)/([\w\d_\-]+)*[A-z0-9]*
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Помогло) Но по группам режет слегка криво, т.к. объединяет все в одну группу все что идет после com и до p. Можете подсказать как исправить?